# Suppressing the default grey horizontal line in density() in R

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density, density-plot

I was wondering if there is an argument to **suppress the default grey horizontal abline** (***see picture below***) that comes with `density()` in R?

```
plot(density(rnorm(1e4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure is, as `?plot.density` tells us:

```
plot(density(rnorm(10000)), zero.line = FALSE)
```

Comment: The trick here is to learn how to look up help pages for methods like `plot.density`. R's way of dealing with methods is a bit odd so it can take some time to get used to it.